# Mysql select all from list and order by date on another list

Tags: mysql, subquery

So I am making a warranty management system. Something to let you know when a warranty is about to end.

I am storing the warranties in a list called warranties, and each warranty renewal in a separate table called warranty_entries.

The `warranties` table only contains an Auto-Increment ID, the product name, the company, who it was made by and the date of creation.

The `warranty_entries` table contains an Auto_Increment ID, the id of the warranty it belongs to, the expiration date, the start date, the date or creation, and a few other fields.

I am trying to select * from `warranties` and order them by the end date of their most current entry in `warranty_entries`.

So a warranties expiration date is the expiration date of the latest expiring warranty entry.

I'll try to rephrase one more time, since I as well am getting confused describing this.
I want to order all the warranties by the expiration date of their most recently created entries' expiration date.

I can't seem to grapple my head around how to only select 1 entry in a table and sort another table by that entries expiration date.

**UPDATE - TABLE STRUCTURE AND DESIRED OUTPUT**

```
TABLE: warranties
-----------------------------------------------------------------
|      id       |       1        |      2        |       3      |
|     name      | chick warranty | duck warranty | cat warranty |  
-----------------------------------------------------------------

TABLE: warranty_entries
----------------------------------------------------
|      id       |  1   |  2   |  3   |  4   |  5   | 
|  warranty_id  |  1   |  2   |  2   |  3   |  3   |
|   end_date    | 2010 | 2005 | 2006 | 2010 | 2015 |
|  start_date   | 2008 | 2001 | 2005 | 2008 | 2010 |
----------------------------------------------------
```

I want to select everything from warranties and order them by the end date of their corresponding entry in warranty_entries. Since there are multiple warranty entries that have the same warranty_id I want to use the most recent end date to order by.

So after the query, the result set would look something like this:

```
RESULT SET:
-----------------------
| id |     name       |
| 3  |  cat warranty  |
| 1  | chick warranty |
| 2  | duck warranty  |
-----------------------
```

Comment: Show your table structure & your desired output you expect

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in a sub query,  like so:

`SELECT w.*, (SELECT end_date FROM warranty_entries we WHERE we.warranty_id = w.id ORDER BY end_date DESC LIMIT 1) AS end FROM warranties w ORDER BY end DESC`

This should do the trick. Change the names of the tables and columns as necessary.

Comment: How would you select entries within a certain date. I can't add the between statement inside the sub query because it wouldn't always pick the newest one.

Comment: You would have to add the between in the sub query and it will pick the newest one between two dates.

Comment: But I only want to pick from the most recent date and check if it is between certain dates. Like check if a warranty's expiration date is between x and y. So it would never select from the non most recent entries per warranty.

Comment: If you want such a check,  use my query and do the check using your processing language like php,  because this logic would become a mess in sql, and it would slow down a lot